# How to print the below number series in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, typescript, numbers

I need to print a number series like below in **javascript**

```
123567101112161718232425
```

After 3 numbers next will be empty. that will increase as 1 number missed, next 2 number missed like that.

Can anyone help me how to do that..

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: @Parthiban Can you explain property this number series property

Comment: if I give one funtion like printnumbers(25) it should print like the series in question. So the condition will be 3 numbers. After 123 -  4 missed, after 567 - 8 and 9 missed. So it'll increase..

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ --- my idea is that you can do a `for` loop to add elements to an array, and then use `array.join('')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might work I believe:

**Idea:** after every 3 numbers, increase the jump count. Before increasing, just add it to the current Number.

```
var retStr = '';

var jump = 1;
var currNum = 1;
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
        retStr  = retStr + (currNum++);
    }
    currNum += jump++;
}
console.log(retStr);
```

> Output:  "123567101112161718232425313233404142505152616263737475"

Comment: Damn, you beat me by a few seconds! :)

Comment: @Connum It worked in the first shot, that too on google chrome: even I was surprised how :P
Glad I could help, Parthiban :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var serie = "";
var skip = 0;
for (var i=1; i<100; i++)
{
  
  serie = serie + i + (i+1) + (i+2)
  
  i= i+2 
  
  skip = skip +1;
  
  i= i + skip;
}

console.log(serie);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 1 ;
var j=1;
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  for(j=count; j<(count+3); j++){
    document.write(j);
  }
  count = j+=i+1;
}
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the problem, it is always better if you can explain why your answer solves the question.  This helps when others view the answer to understand what has changed and why it should be done this way.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Print(N) {
  var arr = [];
    var k =0;
    var p =0 ;
  for (var i = 1; i <= N; i++) {



    arr.push(i + k)

         if (arr.length % 4 == 0) {
      k= k+p ;
            p++;
            k++;
    }




  }
  return console.log(arr);
}

Print(20)
```

Comment: Easiest of all @time complexity